# Can bond units be created only once with one other person in fire emblem fates?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

So I have formed a bond unit with someone. Is it possible to create another bond unit with the same person? I was hoping to help my sister to create one but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the ''guide'' section within the game, you can't form more than one bond per character since it is considered as a unique bond. If you want to test more than one bond with the same character, I suggest you to simply make a unique-purpose save slot at the very moment of creating a bond with your character and simply try all the bonds you want from this saved slot. It will save you time rather than starting from the beginning each time!

Comment: Thank you for the info. I had not realized that the info was there.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible to get bond units from different people with the same avatar, and you can also form multiple bond units with the same person. I have 4 bond units from the same person becuz of this. To me it seems active accessory giving between both avatars increases the likelihood of receiving a bond unit, from my experience anyway. Patience and luck is pretty much needed in the end tho.